# Converting lists of categorical data to numeric vectors with unlabeled data

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, embedding

I am preparing some data for an autoencoder. One of the variables, diag_codes, is a list of codes associated with each observation. They are of varying lengths but have at least one.

My question is, without labels, how should this data be prepared to be ingested into the autoencoder? With over 12,000 codes and only 42,000 observations, I need to somehow vectorize/embed. So far I have tokenized and padded the codes (max length is 31):

[image]

What I would like is to find embeddings for these. Order of the codes does not matter. If I did one-hot encoding first, we would have to shrink from 12,000 variables. Should I be using word2vec?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily convert all columns in dataframe into categories. Here is a simple code sample.

```
import pandas as pd
 
# Intitialise data of lists
data = [{'Year': 2020, 'Airport':2000, 'Casino':5000, 'Stadium':9000, 'Size':'Small'}, 
       {'Year': 2019, 'Airport':3000, 'Casino':4000, 'Stadium':12000, 'Size':'Medium'},
       {'Year': 2018, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':9000, 'Stadium':10000, 'Size':'Medium'},
       {'Year': 2017, 'Airport':5000, 'Casino':10000, 'Stadium':15000, 'Size':'Large'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


df = df.set_index(['Year'])
df
```

Result:

[image]

```
df_fin = pd.DataFrame({col: df[col].astype('category').cat.codes for col in df}, index=df.index)
df_fin
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I am already encoding the codes to integers - what I need to know is how to appropriately embed the codes to a small amount of variables (12kpossible codes, max length 31, 50k observations).

Comment: I don't know what 'vectorize/embed' refers to. I'm not sure what 'appropriately embed the codes to a small amount of variables' means. Do you want to bucket your data? Checkout the link below. Maybe that's what you want. 

https://pbpython.com/pandas-qcut-cut.html